# Goland: Program doesn't stop at debug point

Tags: macos, go, goland

I am trying to debug a simple go the main file. It doesn't stop at debug point at all.

main.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

// This method will return factorial of a number recursively
func iterativeFactorial(n int) int {
    factorial := 1
    for x := n; x >= 1; x-- {
        factorial = factorial * x
    }
    return factorial
}

func main() {
    x := iterativeFactorial(3)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Logs:

> GOROOT=/Users/dilipyadav/sdk/go1.16beta1 #gosetup
> GOPATH=/Users/dilipyadav/go #gosetup
> /Users/dilipyadav/sdk/go1.16beta1/bin/go build -o
> /private/var/folders/qg/pf_jt05s71s8pbl_bbxll3z80000gn/T/___go_build_github_com_dilip2048_data_structure_and_thinking_in_go_chapter02_recursion_and_backtracking
> -gcflags all=-N -l /Users/dilipyadav/githome/data-structure-and-thinking-in-go/chapter02-recursion-and-backtracking/iterative_factorial.go
> #gosetup /Applications/GoLand.app/Contents/plugins/go/lib/dlv/macarm/dlv
> --listen=0.0.0.0:62680 --headless=true --api-version=2 --check-go-version=false --only-same-user=false exec /private/var/folders/qg/pf_jt05s71s8pbl_bbxll3z80000gn/T/___go_build_github_com_dilip2048_data_structure_and_thinking_in_go_chapter02_recursion_and_backtracking
> -- API server listening at: [::]:62680 debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:LLDB  PROJECT:lldb-1205.0.27  for arm64. Got a connection, launched process
> /private/var/folders/qg/pf_jt05s71s8pbl_bbxll3z80000gn/T/___go_build_github_com_dilip2048_data_structure_and_thinking_in_go_chapter02_recursion_and_backtracking
> (pid = 29830).

I have debug point at line `fmt.Println(x)`. It doesn't stop here.

I tried the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038930/debugging-go-application-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoints). It didn't work. I have also tried by installing [delve](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/installation/README.md). This too didn't work.

*Other info:*

**OS**: Mac M1 Apple Silicon

**Goland**: 2021.1.1

**GO**: 1.16.3

Comment: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2436#issuecomment-821857172 can you have a look at this. This worked for me

Comment: My delve version is already 1205.


```dilipyadav@Dilips-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver
debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:LLDB  PROJECT:lldb-1205.0.27
 for arm64.```

Comment: Did you update xcode recently?

Comment: Please follow the instructions here: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2436#issuecomment-835196854

Comment: You need to compile Delve manually with the fix from the master branch: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/commit/4bd16ad7565e89be1ee22b2f7a8f6f8577a3552a

Comment: @s0xzwasd I already tried this.

Comment: What output of the `dlv version` command?